# Create folder from one site in another's folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There is a folder for file uploads on my site `http://mySite/Uploads/`
for each user I want to create  a new folder and save files into it. It works for site visitors/ But i also have an admin site. Employees should be able to upload files with it at the same directory.
Directory.CreateDirectory returns an error, that it can't handle  uri addresses.
 I'm passing `"http://mySite/Uploads/UserId"`. am  i wrong? should i use another mechanisms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone interested. We made virtual folder "uploads" in IIS in both sites. Right click on your site in iis => add virtual folder or somehow, my iis isn't in english. Do it for both sites. and it's full path points at the same folder, so i can use `Server.MapPath("~Uploads")`; and in admin site i get `http://adminSite/Uploads/`, in main site it's `http://mySite/Uploads/`. if i upload files by one address, i allways can get access to them by another.

Answer (score 0):

> am i wrong?

Yes, you should pass a physical folder to the `Directory.CreateDirectory` method and not an url. For example:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/uploads/UserId"));
```

The `Server.MapPath` method should return a folder like this: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\uploads\userid`.

Comment: obviously, i was misunderstood. Server.MapPath("~/uploads/UserId") will give me myadminsite\uploads\UserId   and i want it to be   mymainsite\uploads\UserId

Comment: Then you cannot use the `Server.MapPath` method. This method works only within the same application. If you need to access a folder outside of your application you will have to specify the full path: `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\mymainsite\uploads\userid.`

Answer (score 0):

You must use paths relative to the system root. You can do that with the [`MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath.aspx) method.

```
var uploadsRoot = Server.MapPath("~Uploads");
var userUploadFolder = Path.Combine(UploadsRoot, userId.ToString());
Directory.CreateDirecty(userUploadFolder);
```

Comment: That's exactly what i do to upload from main site's page. but i also need to do it at the same folder from another site/ how is it possible with Server.MapPath? it's mapping to admin site, it's not what i need